# how to set crontab for run each n days from current date?

Tags: cron

I want to run a command  each  n days  in the cronjob, but from the current day

if i use for example:

```
16 23 */7 * * COMMAND
```

Runs `COMMAND` at minute :16, on hour 23, on days 0, 7, 14, 21, 28, every month.

i want that if for example today is 10, run  the days 10, 17, 24 ,etc

any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

`*/7` doesn't run on days 0, 7, 14, 21, 28, every month, but 1, 8, 15, 22, 29 (the numbering of the days in a month start at 1).

If you want to run on days 10, 17, 24, you can write `10-31/7`, or perhaps `3-31/7` if you want to cycle back from the 3rd, on the following month.

(I'd suggest it might make more sense to use the weekly parameter for something that's meant to run every 7 days, since it may run at different intervals at the end of the month otherwise.)

*EDIT:*

When re-reading the question, it seems that `cron` on its own isn't sufficient to achieve what you're after. There's no way of expressing the pattern you want (every n days) in general, since it's always going to be from a specific day of the month, and there may be fewer than n days between the last occurrence in a month and the first of the following month. The only exception to this is for weekly patterns, in which case you can specify the "day of the week" field instead of the "day of the month" field.

To achieve what you want, you may need to combine a cron task that's running every way with a quick test that checks how far from the reference date you are, something similar to [this idea on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72598/2644). (You could probably use bash arithmetic directly instead of having to use `bc`.)

Comment: The output the example i get in this simulator http://cronwtf.github.io/.

the frequency is a parameter provided by the user, so I can not put weekly

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that project for reference. [`man 5 crontab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) would certainly be a better reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have multiple lines in the crontab?

i.e for the nth, nth+x, nth +2x, etc..

Copy 'n' paste will be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at(1) would be a better choice, since it already supports constructs like "now + 3 days" to mean 3 days from now.

Or encode logic in your script to parse the output of "date" - e.g. call out to date +%d to see what the day-of-month was, and do whatever arithmetic you want on that.

General UNIX rule though: if you have to copy and paste a lot, you're doing it wrong :)